# Excel combine and sort rows from multiple sheets with different column indices

Tags: excel

Given the following excel Data on sheet 1

```
column B      column D    column H
date          miles       costs
20-10-13      12500       45
05-03-13      11500       75
```

And the following excel Data on sheet 2

```
column B      column E    column F
date          miles       costs
10-10-13      12000       25
05-03-13      11500       35
```

On sheet, data is available in a similair matter column miles and costs are in different indices as well.

How to combine the data to a new sheet, ordering on date and putting miles in column C and costs in column D. Automatically updating if data is added to either of the sheets and sorting on date.

I tried to make a dynamic Named Range (which always include the latest added row, this works) and than consolidate. However, I get an invalid range.

Any body able to point out a solution direction for me?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you edit your post to show us what output you want e.g. miles in Column C and costs in Column D. I assume you want date in Column B???

Comment: What I tried is consolodite as indicated.

What I expect is on sheet 3 the folowing

    `column B      column E    column F`
    `date          miles       costs`
    `20-10-13      12500       45`
    `10-10-13      12000       25`
    `05-03-13      11500       35`
    `05-03-13      11500       75 `

In SQL, I would use a `JOIN` statement, but now something for Excel which also dynamically updates.
Hope this is possible...

Answer (score 0):

put this in A1 cell of Sheet3 :

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW()),IF(ROW()<=(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)+COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A)),INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,(ROW()-COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A))),""))
```

then drag out. Hope that helps. (: